# Microsoft Graph API Throttling limits

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I read about throttling limits. And it is 10000 requests per 10 minutes. But I have 429 (Too Many Requests) error code after 77 requests. I use Microsoft.Graph 3.8.0 .net core sdk and developers subscription. Maybe developers subscription has it's own limits? Also some of my requests are batch requests (15 requests per each batch). How batch request will be handled? As 1 or as 15 requests?
But 77x15=1155. It's also far from 10000.

Pleas help me figure out this issue

Btw, I test it with message resource

Comment: Could you also mention the APIs that you are calling in the question? The throttling is (service specific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#service-specific-limits)

Comment: I use Mail API resources, perform delete and add message  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: How many requests are you sending in parallel?

Comment: I wrote before. I run it in 1 thread (synchronously) and have exception on 78th request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limits have been deployed to v1 recently for outlook resources (messages, events...) that also impact batching.
Batch items are currently individually towards the limit and the items are processed parallelly which is triggering the 4 concurrent requests limit.
We're investigating how to resolve the issue and updates will be posted on this [thread](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/8760)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, baywet.  I'm also running into this problem.